# kubectl apply reports error "Operation cannot be fulfilled on serviceaccounts"

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a ServiceAccount YAML file which I am applying to a new cluster.

My YAML is like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2019-03-20T23:17:42Z
    name: default
    namespace: dev4
    resourceVersion: "80999"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dev4/serviceaccounts/default
    uid: 5c6e0d09-4b66-11e9-b4e3-0a779a87bb40
  secrets:
  - name: default-token-tl4dd
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"pod-labeler","namespace":"dev4"}}
    creationTimestamp: 2020-04-21T05:46:25Z
    name: pod-labeler
    namespace: dev4
    resourceVersion: "113455688"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dev4/serviceaccounts/pod-labeler
    uid: 702dadda-8393-11ea-abd9-0a768ca51346
  secrets:
  - name: pod-labeler-token-6vgp7
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

When I apply to the new EKS Cluster at version 1.16, by the command `kubectl apply -f <yaml file>`
I get the error as below:

```
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
Error from server (Conflict): Operation cannot be fulfilled on serviceaccounts "default": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
Error from server (Conflict): Operation cannot be fulfilled on serviceaccounts "pod-labeler": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `resourceVersion`, `selfLink` and `uid` from the yaml before applying. Kubernetes maintains consistency of objects using version and trying to override it with a wrong version leads to this error.

```
resourceVersion: "80999"
selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dev4/serviceaccounts/default
uid: 5c6e0d09-4b66-11e9-b4e3-0a779a87bb40
...
resourceVersion: "113455688"
selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dev4/serviceaccounts/pod-labeler
uid: 702dadda-8393-11ea-abd9-0a768ca51346
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, however, it gave me a warning. Is that warning safe to be ignored? The second question is do I have to follow the same thing for other objects like secrets, configmaps, deployments, replicasets, statefulsets?

Comment: This won't work. The resourceVersion is needed for the update